# I want to replace some wrongly assigned elements from the dataframe in python based on the previous elements

Tags: string, dataframe, replace, conditional-statements, partial

```
Station_ID
ID809086
t
ID809088
ID809089
.
.
ID809098
t
ID809100
.
.
.
```

Basically I want to replace all 't' with previous ID +1, such as t = ID809087 and ID809099 in above scenario.  Thanks in advance

Basically I want to replace all 't' with previous ID +1, such as t = ID809087 and ID809099 in above scenario.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
tmp = 'ID' + df['Station_ID'].str.extract(r'^ID(\d+)')[0].astype(float).interpolate().astype(int).astype(str)

df['Station_ID'] = np.where(df['Station_ID'].eq('t'), tmp, df['Station_ID'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Station_ID
0   ID809086
1   ID809087
2   ID809088
3   ID809089
4   ID809098
5   ID809099
6   ID809100
```